# Monitoring Dynamics AX with New Relic

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, newrelic, dynamics-ax-2012

Is it possible to use the New Relic monitoring suite with Dynamics AX?
Looking at the options New Relic seems to have an option for .Net applications.  As Dynamics has some integration with .Net we wondered if it were possible to use this tool?

Googling for this I found no sign of people having attempted previously.

Comment: The AX 2012 CIL is managed .Net so I don't see why a monitoring tool couldn't attach to these processes. I know its not an answer but may be worth trying using evaluation copied if you have access to either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be possible, but that depends a great deal on the how the Dynamics AX applications was designed.  At the very least you will need to make sure the .Net Agent installation includes the **Instrument All .NET Applications** feature.  Next, you will need to tell the .Net Agent to instrument the application. How that is done depends on whether or not Dynamics AX uses an app.config file.

If Dynamics AX has an app.config you can adding two appSetting's similar to:

```
<add key="NewRelic.AppName" value="MyCustomName"/>
<add key="NewRelic.AgentEnabled" value="true"/>
```

If Dynamics AX doesn't have an app.config you can update the instrumentation element in the **newrelic.config** found in **%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\New Relic.NET Agent** to look similar to:

```
<instrumentation log="false">
  <applications>
    <application name="MyService1.exe" />
  </applications>
</instrumentation>
```

You can see more about this [here](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/dotnet/instrumenting-custom-applications) and [here](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/dotnet/dotnet-agent-configuration#instrumentation).

Comment: That's great, thanks @NR_Jacob.  I'll give it a go tomorrow / will mark this as selected answer after if all works.  Thanks again.

Comment: I dont think you will find a dynamics ax app.config, as the system is made up of a number of integrated software packages. You may wish to monitor all your AOS services, enterprice portal, client apps, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  @AnthonyBlake: you're right, there is no App.config; so I had to use the instrumentation option suggested by NR_Jacob.  In terms of the different components that's ok - monitoring of an AOS is my main aim, though once achieved I'll look into what else we're able to monitor.

Comment: @NR_Jacob: your solution works in as much as NewRelic's log file show's it's finding the exe I named (i.e. it determines the correct path for the exe, so is clearly working to some extent), but nothing's getting back to the site (though with the server monitoring feature information is getting back - so it's not a proxy issue).  I'm not sure what language AX was written in; I'm guessing it's not .Net, despite having elements which are .net compatible.

Comment: @JohnLBevan see my original comment John, you will only be able to monitor the CIL in AX 2012 as it is managed (.net). I think you will struggle with other elements.